# Stack structure pointing to itself - What's going on here?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

```
typedef struct _s {     // same definition as before   
    int         value;
    struct _s   *next;
}  STACKITEM;

STACKITEM    *stack = NULL;

 ....

void push_item(int newvalue)
{
    STACKITEM  *new = malloc( sizeof(STACKITEM) );  

    if(new == NULL) {     // check for insufficient memory   
        perror("push_item");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    new->value   = newvalue;
    new->next    = stack;
    stack        = new;
}
```

What is the purpose of the two lines:

```
new->next    = stack;
stack        = new;
```

From what I can see, the next field of the new STACKITEM structure is set to point to stack. Stack is then set to point to the STACKITEM structure new? Is this correct?

If so, I do not understand what the point of this is. It seems like it is 'wrapping' the stack around and 'closing' it. In other words, when we attempt to access the next structure in the stack, since this is actually the last structure available, it can only access itself?

Thank you.

Comment: why would new will be null? instead, you have to use `stack==NULL` then put stack=new

Comment: The new node's `next` pointer points to the current stack-top, then the stack-top points the new node. Think about where the aftermath stack-top now points, and how you would get to the *prior* stack top.

Comment: @WhozCraig please elaborate. Also, what do you mean by 'node'? Are you referring to a structure?

Comment: Overall it is pretty weird practice to create a linked list on the heap and call it "stack"... FIFO might be a better term to use.

Comment: @Lundin Except it's a LIFO.

Comment: @WhozCraig A stack ADT is a LIFO certainly. But a single-linked list with a "head" node is something else.

Comment: @Lundin sure. Now if there exists any curriculum in academic data structures that does *not* use a stack for the initial example when introducing the LIFO concept, I've yet to see it (nor has the OP, apparently). We all start gotta start somewhere, I suppose.

Comment: @ThePointer To understand the purpose of those two lines, it helps to look at the `pop_item` function. The `pop_item` function removes the first item from the list, and whatever the first item's `next` pointer points to becomes the first item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep focus on this:

- `stack` will always be (a) pointing to the dynamic node at the "top" of your stack, or (b) NULL if the stack is empty.
- When a newely allocated STACKSTRUCT node is to be pushed, in the end `stack` must point to that node, but first that newly allocated structure's `next` pointer must point to previous *prior* value of `stack` before the add (and change to `stack`).

My ascii art is terrible, so I'm not going to bother. Rather, I've prepared a simple example that uses your code, but adds a `print_stack` to dump the current state of the stack when each new node is added:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _s {     // same definition as before
    int         value;
    struct _s   *next;
}  STACKITEM;

STACKITEM    *stack = NULL;

void print_stack()
{
    STACKITEM const* item = stack;
    for (; item != NULL; item = item->next)
        printf("%p : { value=%d; next=%p }\n", item, item->value, item->next);
    fputc('\n', stdout);
}

void push_item(int newvalue)
{
    STACKITEM *new = malloc( sizeof(STACKITEM) );

    if(new == NULL) // check for insufficient memory
    {
        perror("push_item");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("push.1: stack = %p, new = %p\n", stack, new);
    new->value = newvalue;
    new->next = stack;
    stack = new;
    printf("push.2: stack = %p, new->next = %p\n", stack, new->next);
    print_stack();
}

int main()
{
    for (int i=1; i<=5; ++i)
        push_item(i);
}
```

<sub>Note: this knowingly leaks every node. memory management isn't the point of this; *node* management is.</sub>

The output of this will vary from implementation and machine (lots of pointer values being printed). Follow the pointer values to see how this all wires together. Remember, this output shows the stack in top-down order (i.e. the first item in each printout is the "top" of the stack). Also note that each of these dumps starts with the node pointed to by `stack` *after* the push has been completed.

**Sample Output**

```
push.1: stack = 0x0, new = 0x1001054f0
push.2: stack = 0x1001054f0, new->next = 0x0
0x1001054f0 : { value=1; next=0x0 }

push.1: stack = 0x1001054f0, new = 0x100105500
push.2: stack = 0x100105500, new->next = 0x1001054f0
0x100105500 : { value=2; next=0x1001054f0 }
0x1001054f0 : { value=1; next=0x0 }

push.1: stack = 0x100105500, new = 0x100105510
push.2: stack = 0x100105510, new->next = 0x100105500
0x100105510 : { value=3; next=0x100105500 }
0x100105500 : { value=2; next=0x1001054f0 }
0x1001054f0 : { value=1; next=0x0 }

push.1: stack = 0x100105510, new = 0x100105520
push.2: stack = 0x100105520, new->next = 0x100105510
0x100105520 : { value=4; next=0x100105510 }
0x100105510 : { value=3; next=0x100105500 }
0x100105500 : { value=2; next=0x1001054f0 }
0x1001054f0 : { value=1; next=0x0 }

push.1: stack = 0x100105520, new = 0x100200000
push.2: stack = 0x100200000, new->next = 0x100105520
0x100200000 : { value=5; next=0x100105520 }
0x100105520 : { value=4; next=0x100105510 }
0x100105510 : { value=3; next=0x100105500 }
0x100105500 : { value=2; next=0x1001054f0 }
0x1001054f0 : { value=1; next=0x0 }
```

Notice how in each case, the new structure's `next` pointer is assigned the current value of `stack`, then the `stack` pointer is assigned the new structure's address. Once complete, the structure has been "pushed" onto the stack and the new stack top reflect this. Further, the `next` pointer of that structure now provides a pointer to the original stack top, thereby providing the linked-list chain needed for the data structure.

Comment: What do you mean by 'node' ?

Comment: @ThePointer one of your allocated structures. Seriously, if that term has never been used in whatever class/tutorial you're learning from, its the most bizarrely versed data structures course I've ever seen.

Comment: So in other words, new ends up pointing to the old top of the stack, and stack ends up pointing at the new top of the stack, which is new? This way, stack is always pointing to the structure on the top of the stack?

Comment: @ThePointer If can find *anywhere* in the code, or text, I posted, where "`new` ends up pointing to the old stack top" I'd like to know where. I said, `new->next` points to the old stack top, not `new`. *after* that happens, only *then* do you assign `stack = new`, thereby making the stack top now be the newest added node. I'm literally running out of ways to say it, so that's my last shot. *Look at the output* in the posted answer and follow the pointer values with each newly added structure. The formation of the linked list chain should be evident.

Comment: Sorry, that was what I meant. Imprecise use of language on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
new->next    = stack;
stack        = new;
```

Above lines of code are very important to create link between two nodes. Here what happens is lets understand with an example.

Let's assume you are creating a link-list for values `1,2` and `3` only. So what will happen when you pass the first value as `1` is, value `1` will be stored at node1 `new->value =1` and the next member of your node the pointer will be given value as `new->next    = stack;`, which means the pointer is null for the first node right now and the global `stack` has the address of the first node.

Now you are entering the second value as `2` so now, first memory will be allocated for the `new` and then value 2 will be assigned as `new->value =2` and the `next` pointer will contain the address of the first node as `stack` contains address of first node. And the `stack` is being assigned with the address of the second node. So now link between the first node and second node has been created.

For the third value `3` it goes same as above.

Basically this the `add_at_begin` method of `single linklist`. Here everytime stack is been assigned with the address of the current node and next time is being assigned to the `next` pointer which is creating the link.